# Cloudflare CNAME Error 1014 Cross-User Banned

Tags: dns, github-pages, cloudflare

I previously had my GitHub pages site set up correctly with my custom domain and my Cloudflare DNS, however, I was playing around with my CNAME records but decided I wanted to revert back to how things were before.

I set my CNAME records to what they were previously, however, when I go to my custom domain I get the error.

`Error 1014: CNAME Cross-User Banned`

Never seen this error before, how can I fix this. Screenshots of settings attached

*GitHub*
[image]

*Cloudflare*
[image]

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Maybe Github is using Cloudflare? I'll post here if I find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solving it for me.

https://twitter.com/stefanprodan/status/834872543790174209

> @stefanprodan -
> 1:08 PM - 23 Feb 2017
>
> If you use #Cloudflare with #Github pages change your CNAME to
> http://github.map.fastly.net  to fix Error 1014 CNAME Cross-User
> Banned